# Marking particular questions / answers as definitive

Tags: feature-request

In a way this is more a feature request / request for clarification.

So, I'm a SQL guy and I follow a bunch of the SQL tags. Every day, there are duplicate questions, primarily of a primitive / introductory nature. I'm sure there are many other questions which are *essentially* duplicates but are differently worded or patterned enough to avoid detection.

These questions are (for the large part) homework questions - or, worse, do my work questions! - requesting specific implementations of common SQL patterns (windowing, pivots, concatenation, update joins, etc.) Since SO is ostensibly supposed to be a wiki / knowledge repository and not just an endless support queue, do we have a tidying up process whereby we declare certain questions the *definitive*<sup>1</sup> answer?

As an example, consider the dynamic pivot. Pivoting a value across a dynamic set of values from another column is apparently the Platonic ideal of "I don't want to know how to dynamically pivot something, I want someone to write my dynamic pivot for me", as [a current search for "[sql] [pivot] dynamic" on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+%5Bpivot%5D+dynamic) brings up **868** results (plus [168 more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D%20%5Bpivot%5D%20dynamic%20-%5Bsql%5D) for just "[sql-server] [pivot] dynamic -[sql]", and hundreds more using sundry flavors of tags to ensure the questions are overwhelmingly about dynamic pivoting in SQL.)

These questions are for the most part unloved: 0 votes, 1 answer, some sharp-eyed guru got some cheap rep, and life goes on.

What I am envisioning is the definitive "dynamic pivot for SQL Server" question which might entail:

- A pseudocode solution / background for the solution;
- A platform-specific implementation (allowing some flavor for different versions, dependencies, etc.)
- A list of quirks, exceptions to the rule, etc.

Whenever somebody posts a question about dynamic pivots, rather than simply marking it as a duplicate, we could promote these questions over others in search results. We could award reputation as good as an answer for directing respondents to these definitive questions and having them accept them.

We could tag these questions as usual and add an extra tab to the tag pages for "definitive" which could look more like a traditional wiki list / table of contents with some curation or structure.

I think of this process more as a SEO-enhancing element of SO, whereby searching for dynamic pivots as above returns fewer, more idiosyncratic results that are more useful to someone searching for a specific problem with a dynamic pivot and not merely "How do I do a dynamic pivot?", "Help me write a stored procedure that returns a dynamic pivot", etc. This is my ultimate goal for this feature, and so if there are existing methods that could produce the same result, by all means enlighten me.

Surely I can't be the first person to have thought this, and so, yes, ironically this question may be a duplicate or "asked and answered" but if so, I would like to see where those discussions went and what steps I can take to make this sort of thing a reality.

---

1. Yeah, I have no idea either. But that's what crowdsourcing communities are for, right?

Comment: Similar/related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116087/another-take-on-canonical-answers-add-a-canonical-vote

Comment: [Collaborative lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182572/165773): "There are a small handful of questions that are not exactly appropriate for Stack Overflow, are popular and have useful answers where the primary value arises from the community's regular efforts to keep them updated via edits... The intent here is to emphasize the one valid use of Community Wiki: Community wiki is for that rare gem of a post that needs true community collaboration..."

Answer (score 4):

So we have several steps here.

- Writing a canonical question

  Clearly you can do this already.  Nothing is stopping you from writing the canonical question as you have described it.
- Closing the question as a duplicate of a more general, canonical question

  Again, this can be done already, and is done in certain situations.  Arguably less often than it should be, but clearly the site functionality is there for this.
- Promote canonical questions in search results

  Assuming the previous points are followed, this happens naturally.  The canonical questions tend to generate lots of votes, incoming links, views, etc., all of which improves it's SEO (in both Google and SO's search algorithms).  On top of that, if all of the very similar questions get closed as duplicates, you don't have a bunch of similar questions to sift through to find the good one.
- Provide some means of making the question visually distinct to make it clear that it's a more wiki-style post that is collaboratively edited

  This is what Community Wiki is specifically designed for.
- Give people rep for directing people to the canonical post instead of answering

  So here we're to the only real feature request that hasn't yet been implemented.  It's [not an original request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions). (Also see the linked/related posts, as there are a lot of duplicates of that question.)

  To summarize a few main points, there are problems.  There is potential for abuse (people will just close questions as a duplicate even when they're different, just for the easy rep), there needs to be enough of an incentive for people to take the time to find the duplicates instead of answering, and yet as the incentive goes up the incentive to abuse the system *also* goes up.  Then do you provide a reward for people voting to close that didn't first propose the duplicate?  If yes, people will just go along with any other proposal for the rep, if not, people will post answers instead of voting to close.

Comment: I agree with all your points, but it seems like the laissez-faire mechanisms for answer promotion / SEO aren't doing as good a job as they ought, so perhaps a little more incentives for curation are in order (with mindfulness towards the potential for abuse you pointed out.)

Comment: @KyleHale As mentioned, that only works so long as people generally close questions as duplicates instead of answering them, when they don't, that doesn't happen.

Comment: perhaps the loss of rep involved in community wiki is working against us here?  writing and maintaining canonical answers takes _more_ work than answering specific questions, yet doing the Right Thing and making them CW also takes away the reward.

Comment: @Eevee Look through a number of the existing canonical questions out there; for quite a lot of them the contributions of the original author end up being fairly small.  Yes, it can potentially be a lot of work, but that work gets amortized across all of the different editors.