# What should we do with "MySQL reserved keywords" questions?

Tags: discussion

On Stack Overflow, there are **a lot** of questions where people use reserved keywords as identifiers (such as table and column names) and complain that their query is not working. A quick Google search query `"mysql" "is a reserved keyword" site:stackoverflow.com` turns up **23,000** results. Even if we consider 50% of them as false positives, there are still a lot of questions.

Most of them has an answer that goes like:

> `FOO` is a reserved keyword. You should wrap it in backticks, like so:  `FOO`

Some examples:

- [Where is the error in this MySQL syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689734/where-is-the-error-in-mysql-syntax)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152974/you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your?rq=1
- [MySQLSyntaxErrorException with table name "condition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881049/mysqlsyntaxerrorexception-with-table-name-condition)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135645/cant-insert-database-with-mysql

As I see it, the issue originates from a simple mistake and is not going to benefit many people in the future. Such questions result in answers that repeat the same information over and over again. This pollutes the site with *bad* content.

There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. Close these questions as a typographical error. I think the following close-reason fits the bill:

   > This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner **unlikely to help future readers**. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.
2. Create a canonical Q&A pair that addresses the problem, and close these questions as a duplicate of that one.

I'd like to hear your thoughts about this. Do you think this is useful? Which one do you think is the best approach, and why?

Comment: Yes, I think it is useful.

Comment: Don't close as off-topic, close as duplicates of the canonical question.

Comment: Concur: Close as duplicates of a canonical question.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: this has already been done for other types of questions, like [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) The community and the mods approve of this process, for the most part (see @Robert's first comment under his [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253026/176646) to a related question). Also, see this similar question from last week: [Marking particular questions / answers as definitive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252018/176646)

Comment: Now that you mentioned, MySQL should have a `reserved keyword` error.

Comment: I was just going through the close queue, and there are already lots of these questions that have lots of off-topic/typo close votes. I'm not sure it really matters which we use, as I doubt these questions are helpful to future reader, because they're not going to find them when searching. The error message is too generic.

Comment: I fully agree, though a minor adjustment seems needed. `...the issue is originating from a simple typographical mistake and is not going to benefit many people in the future.` With 23,000 hits for that specific search, it seems that a lot of benefit is possible. As such, definitely at least a 'canonical' reference is called for.

Comment: @user2338816: If all those questions about a simple typographical mistake were benefiting people then those people wouldn't have to repost it 22,999 times.

Comment: Just putting this out there - [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+reserved+keyword+is%3Aanswer) are probably a good starting point for questions to look at to close as duplicates of [the canonical post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/why-cant-i-use-certain-words-as-table-column-names-in-mysql?lq=1).

Comment: Yeah, close as dups of that, but that canonical question should also be added to the FAQs IMO.

Comment: I am guilty of asking this one, because when you are missing something it's much harder to find the `at ""` instead of the `at "blahblahblah"`. However it really is down to the lack of research most of the time because SQL and MySQL syntax really is very simple, and there are multitudes of syntax guides out there (I have 3 favourited).

Comment: With all respect, this seems like one of the biggest 'rep-whoring' posts I've seen in a while - I appreciate the suggestions, and a canonical question is great and all, but based upon the values as I write this, you've garnered +280 rep out of this thus far, with a suggestion to link *every other question to the canonical one you created*. I would anticipate you're going to get a lot more rep because of that...

Comment: @RobertH: So what? Community wikis are for questions requiring extensive input from many different people. This one is just a single Q & A pair. I don't see why it should be made CW. And seriously, why do you bother to calculate how much reputation (which are meaningless internet points anyway) I *garner* from this post? If *I* am a repwhore for wanting to create a canonical reference so we could close the future dupes, what would you call those people who **repeatedly** answer such questions?

Comment: @AmalMurali YourCommonSense already called them rep-whores. Many of the answers posted bring up a variation of the same basic theme - Why create a new question/answer when there are existing ones to choose from? As YourCommonSense put it - why would people refrain from easy prey? Especially considering that GordonLinoff makes a great point in saying the same answer can have multiple questions that may *appear* unrelated. Your canonical question makes AlmaDo's xkcd quote bang on.

Comment: "Oh no, someone is getting rep from a post" is not and has never been a reason to convert something to community wiki. (cc @RobertH) If it turns out that the canonical question and the answer are being continuously maintained by multiple people, we can think about flipping the switch. In the meantime, calling people rep whores for posting what is objectively good, well-intentioned, and well-written content is, at best, counterproductive.

Comment: @AnnaLear Was just my 2 cents. I never mentioned converting it to a CW anyway. I understand that this is an issue that has no 'silver bullet' for a resolution and in fact a canonical post may be the best solution for it; however my understanding of Meta is to discuss SO and it's practices. Playing devil's advocate is something that should be done regardless of the discussion and I felt it valid to introduce that point as what will stop the next person from making *another* canonical post for the same reasons?

Comment: @RobertH Re. "what will stop the next person from making another canonical post for the same reasons?" Nothing, but I don't see that as a real problem. Simply close the new canonical post as a dupe of the first one, or vice versa, depending on which is better. Either way, new questions can be closed as dupes of one of the posts instead of being answered ad infinitum.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot precisely my point. It's not canonical if it can be closed as a dupe, its just an answer. Perhaps having a 'mark post as canonical' option for the mods to use would help this process. Canonical posts can then be placed at the top of the close as duplicate list, or some similar functionality.

Comment: If we are going to have "Reference Questions", then remove the points from them so they truly are simply to help the community vs just bulking up the points of the poster.  Otherwise we encourage the posting of self answered questions and the request to have all dupes closed and pointed at the so called "reference question" don't have an ulterior motive.

Comment: @RobertH Similar ideas have been [proposed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108579/canonical-answers-for-repeated-questions). Personally, I agree with [agf's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108584/234299) that such a feature isn't necessary. When enough community members close questions as dupes of a single post, it will appear in the list of frequent questions.

Comment: @RobertH As for rep-whoring, see Robert Harvey's rather unpopular [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204214/234299) to automatically community-wikify self answers to encourage people to write canonical posts. The consensus seemed to be that if somebody is willing to put their time and effort into writing a question and answer that will help users and improve the site as a whole, they should be rewarded for it.

Comment: [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql) is now #6 in the list of frequent questions for the [tag:mysql] tag.

Comment: @AnnaLear: What grates against me isn't the rep, or the attempt to contribute a canonical reference post (indeed, the former is designed to encourage the latter and so both should be welcomed in this case).  What grates against me is the *way* in which this has been done.  To put at the top of the question "*this is the canonical reference, close everything else against this one*" and then to post on Meta to get everyone's attention... it's just... well, uncouth.

Comment: @eggyal: If you take a look at the dates (and the [revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/253345/revisions)), you can very well see that the Meta discussion was posted *before* the question was created (asking for recommendations on what should we do with the situation).

Comment: Why only `MySQL`? Is this not a problem across technologies/languages? Shouldn't such a [reference/canonical question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql) be applicable irrespective of a tag? Will we have another similar reference QA separately for `SQLServer` because backticks won't apply there; or `C` or `C#` or `VB` and we might end up with a hundred such reference QA?

Comment: @abhitalks Not all database engines will necessarily give the same error for using a reserved word. Nor do all engines use the same set of reserved words. Nor will the solutions be the same for all engines; in MySQL, one solution is to use backticks, but that won't work for others. So no, you simply *can't* write an answer of reasonable length that is engine agnostic.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: That exactly is the part of my point. How many such reference questions? One for each technology? Or is it just better to pick one from several available dupes and use that to point to rather than create a new question.

Comment: @abhitalks As evidenced by [Alma Do's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253416/176646) and the ensuing comments, there often isn't a suitable duplicate that's broad enough to cover multiple questions. And who cares if there's a canonical answer for each technology? If somebody writes a quality question and answer that can be used to help clean up the site, I think that's a good thing. The upvotes on the reference question and answer Amal wrote also indicate to me that the community thinks this is a good thing.

Comment: here is my attempt at a canonical answer.

Comment: Taken from a comment I left in [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24207846/) - 
I also thought the same thing as to why didn't the programmers implement some form of mechanism to say *"The word `to` is a reserved word...."*. Yet, that would mean that there would need some form of list that SQL would have to go through first and this list stands at changing. I'm sure someone thought about it before, yet this would constitute as a pre-query and could slow down the query process. --- Then read the comment I left after that one, related to inexperienced coding practices.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I have no idea why it is the way it is, but I don't see how closing these questions as duplicates does *not* help. Could you put up your reasoning in a separate answer?

Comment: @AmalMurali Posted, as requested, with a few minor adjustments.

Answer (score 58):

I don't think that accidentally using a reserved keyword is a simple typographical issue; it's an issue of not knowing all the keywords, which is the kind of language knowledge issue that is the mainstay of Stack Overflow.

Such questions should be closed as duplicates, not as typographical errors. That way, others who land on the question through a search will have a link to the canonical answer.

Comment: The "simple typographical issue" is `use backticks`.  You won't hit this error if you do that, and don't need to memorize all the keywords either.  Other than that, yeah, closing a a duplicate is better.

Comment: @Izkata Oh my god someone finally agrees with me! Backtick all the table/column names and there's no need to worry! Seriously, not using backticks is akin to typing `$foo = bar;` in PHP. Sure, it'll work, but only if `bar` is not a constant.

Comment: @Niet Backticks are not portable, so that's not a great solution if there's a chance that your query will run on something other than MySQL in the future.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I'm pretty sure if you're porting an entire project from MySQL to another database thingy, you'd have bigger problems than ``s/(?<=`)[^`]+(?=`)//``

Comment: Here is my attempt at a canonical SQL answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23833632/659190

Answer (score 22):

No matter what you do.
No matter what excellent solution you propose.
No matter how many people would agree with you.

## It will never work.

As can be seen from the linked questions, this is a "[bike shed problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality)" which is HUGELY appreciated by the crowd - a question of the kind that brings nearly **a hundred rep points** for an answer that takes *only a dozen seconds to write*. Means no rep-whore would voluntarily refrain from such an easy prey.

Honestly, all these questions aren't closed all because you are the first to spot their repetitiveness. They aren't closed due to a **flawed system.**

Comment: It's easy to complain that the system is flawed. What alternative solution do you propose?

Comment: @Amal there are already hundreds, if not thousands of proposals on Meta, many of them highly upvoted. But SE doesn't act on them and the value of piling on yet another suggestion seems doubtful.

Comment: @Pekka웃: I agree. But I don't see why a canonical question shouldn't be created to fight the future dupes? We can't make SE implement the suggestions right now. Why not do what we can?

Comment: @AmalMurali Speaking from the Java canonical posts for NullPointerException and pass by reference - it could work, to some extent - a lot of questions get closed as duplicates, but having the canonical post gain enough traction such that most know about it is difficult (so that it (quickly) gets closed), and there will always be people answering the questions (instead?) before it's closed, because they can do so faster than we can close it, and they'll likely get reputation for that.

Comment: who said it shouldn't be created? Honestly, to create one, one don't need even to post on meta. Just create (or choose) a canonical answer and start closing. As simple as that.

Comment: I've got something in the works that will allow closing of duplicates _much_ faster, which will curtail this to a degree. Yes, we want people answering questions, but we also want to encourage people to research and search _first_. If users with _a lot_ of experience in a tag can quickly close duplicates, these won't stay open long enough for the usual semi-crappy 6 word answer. We've gotta overhaul how duplicates are displayed, too, but we're hoping to have some changes out next week.

Comment: @TimPost: Great news. Looking forward to it!

Comment: @YourCommonSense can someone please fix "`aren't got closed`" to "`aren't closed`". :O otherwise, reasonable answer.

Comment: @Killrawr thank you for the correction. But can't you fix it yourself? I thought anyone can edit any post on SO and meta as well

Comment: @YourCommonSense pardon, but not for users with rep < 2000. Users cannot suggest edit on Meta. They will see a disabled (greyed) "edit" instead.

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks, didn't know it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the `edit` button is disabled :/

Comment: Maybe a system where terms commonly found in questions closed as duplicates (by common, I mean cases like this where there are massive numbers), and then if a question contains those terms, when the question is posted, show the asker the accepted answer from the canonical question - if they accept it, mark as a duplicate. That way some duplicates could get caught without moderation.

Answer (score 8):

## TL;DR

I think we should use **existing** good answers as a reference. Because there's literally nothing more else to say rather than extract the corresponding point from manual and provide a link. This is trivial problem - and, while I agree that it needs to have canonical answer, we already have such answers. We only need to decide which is better.

If we'll create new thread, it's like *"`We have 14 different standards!` => `What a mess, we should invent new once and for all!` => `...` => `We have 15 different standards` ..."*

## Existing threads

Actually, we have long list of similar questions:

- [How do I escape reserved words used as column names? MySQL/Create Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table)
- [Using reserved words in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725233/using-reserved-words-in-column-names)
- [Is “key” a reserved word in MySqli? I'm getting an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725233/using-reserved-words-in-column-names)

And so on. Thus, I appreciate the efforts, but I can't see what's the difference with existing answers - because extracting (quotation) some part from manual doesn't make any difference. So, please, inspect existing answers before creating new *reference*.

Comment: Now, please, _explain_ your dv. Because I can't see how [_another duplicate_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/why-cant-i-use-certain-words-as-table-column-names-in-mysql) (which is incomplete, btw) will help a case

Comment: [First question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/) — does not contain any actual explanation on the subject. [Second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725233/) — Only contains a single answer that suggests the use of backticks as a solution. [Third question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725233/) — the same. In short: **those questions address a localized issue and wasn't meant to be "reference question"**.

Comment: First question __does contain__ all the explanation. It only hasn't extraction from the manual (but it has link to there). More, it contains ANSI-mode stuff which your current reference doesn't. Other questions I've put just to show that there are _lots_ of duplicates

Comment: Those are not the only duplicates. As I mentioned in the question here, "*A quick Google search query "mysql" "is a reserved keyword" site:stackoverflow.com turns up 23,000 results.*". Also, "use backtick to fix yer problemz" isn't the answer to this question. The correct solution here is to ***not*** reserved words in the first place, which my answer explains while others do not.

Comment: So what? How does that solve the problem? Google will almost always return thousands links. And - btw, that's how I've found _existing good answers_. Then why don't use them? If the word "backtick" wasn't mentioned there, it's not a problem - because solution with backticks _is listed there_

Comment: There may be a good existing question and answer for this, but none of those are it (and a good answer, which none of those contain, for the reasons Amal mentioned, to a localized question doesn't make it a good candidate to close questions as duplicates of).

Comment: @Dukeling I disagree. Neither small formatting + quotation _doesn't worth_ to be a reference - nor the problem worth to have (such) reference. Because it's well enough to have such answer like I've listed. More, if someone couldn't understand that answer (or will find it "vague" because of "too localized") - good chances are - that person wouldn't understand any reference. Or else: if this problem needs to have that reference, than almost all problems need. Why then we have old good answers for that problems?

Comment: Source of the standards quote: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @AlmaDo the first question is deficient because it doesn't make clear that there are many reserved words or that failure to escape them results in a syntax error with no additional explanation. Somebody whose question about a syntax error gets closed as a dupe of that question is likely to (quite reasonably) ask "wtf does this have to do with my syntax error?"

Answer (score 5):

Closing these questions as duplicates calls into question exactly what duplicates are.  For instance, here are two examples (made up, but I'm sure they are in questions somewhere):

```
insert into t(col1, col2, key)
    values (1, 2, 3)
```

And:

```
select o.*
from order
```

Both of these have the same problem -- the use of keywords without escape characters.  For those not familiar with MySQL, `key` and `order` are key words that should be enclosed in backticks.  I don't think that an answer to the first ("You need backticks around 'key'") is particularly helpful -- to a newbie for the second question.

It is impossible for me to suggest that these two questions would be duplicates.  The *answers* are the same, but the questions are *not*.  Something like `1+1` versus `2*2 - 2`.  And the answer could start with "Learn some arithmetic."

Personally, I don't think that Stack Overflow has addressed this situation adequately.  It is one thing to say that a knowledgeable person knows that the answer is the same.  It is another thing for a less experienced person to recognize this.  In a sense, if you know the answer is a duplicate, you don't need Stack Overflow to answer the question.  A chicken-and-egg problem.

How do I personally deal with this?  I will often put this type of answer in a comment and hope that the OP deletes the question.  The work to find the exact duplicate question is hard ("Oh, which question has the `select` query with the keyword `key` in it?" is different from "Which question just says reserved words need to be escaped?").

Comment: This is the exact purpose for the duplicates - one finds their respective question and then follows the link for the answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense . . . I just added this:   "I don't think that an answer to the first ("You need backticks around 'key'" is particularly helpful -- to a newbie for the second question)".  This is the point.  An expert recognizes the difference, but the person asking the question clearly doesn't.  And, if you looked through those questions, you would see a wide variety of use-cases, which might compound the problem by having PDO, java, prepared statements, joins, and other confounding issues.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: If the answers to these questions are clearly different, then don't close it. Answer them. I'm talking about the thousands of questions which do not involve any other issues except the use of reserved keywords. **They all have the same problem.** They all use reserved keywords and that's the solution to their problem. Currently we have "FOO is a reserved word, escape it in backticks" scattered over in a thousand different questions — why not close them as duplicates of a canonical question?

Comment: @AmalMurali . . . Because "KEY is a reserved word" is a different answer from "ORDER is a reserved word".  If you mark the second as a duplicate of the first, then the OP is not really closer to knowing *which* word is causing the problem.  I'm not against marking these as duplicates, but with lots and lots of reserved words, it seems hard to do so consistently in a way that helps newbies (who would be asking these questions).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I'm not suggesting that we close one question that deals with a specific problem as a duplicate of another. I'm saying we should create a **canonical question** that explains ***how* to solve the problem in general** (i.e. by not using reserved words as identifiers) and optionally explain that it can also be resolved by escaping the identifier with a backtick. **Fix a bug, and that's all you did. Teach how to debug, and you fixed them all.**

Comment: @AmalMurali . . . My fundamental problem with "duplicate question" is that it doesn't cover the situation of "same answer as".  There are definitely cases of duplicate questions.  I think there are more cases of "same answer as".  This, however, is not an option.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Are you arguing that the question must be an exact duplicate of the canonical question, instead of the canonical question encompassing the duplicate and thus its answers being more useful and much more thorough answers for the restricted question?

Comment: There's no chicken and egg; if the asker knew how to find the answer, they wouldn't have asked the question _at all_, dupe or not. There's no significant difference between "The answer to your problem appears below your post" and "The answer appears at the other end of this link on the same website". The point is that there are two goals: 1) get this person a solution to their problem 2) maintain a high-quality, easily-searchable archive of the solutions for future readers. Closing as duplicate _fulfills both those goals_; having answers spread across multiple questions hinders the second.

Comment: @Deduplicator . . . I'm arguing that a newbie should be able to recognize it as a duplicate when pointed out, not an expert.

Comment: @GordonLinoff At a glance or after reading? A newbie will welcome getting the whole picture (he might have some additional questions after reading though). A noob is beyond help as he resists knowledge anyway.

Comment: I picture a teacher teaching a class - would they rather extensively explain **once** that you might get that error if you use a reserved word, possibly give a list of reserved words, mention how to deal with it, etc. (and referring back to that explanation when asked a question about it) or would they deal with question after question about this, giving an extensive explanation each time? In a more code-wise metaphor - would you rather have minor variations of a function written hundreds of times, or have one single function that isn't much more complex than any of the variations.

Comment: @Dukeling . . . I don't disagree, but I don't see the relevance.  An answer that says "quote reserved words" or "`key` is a reserved word use quotes" may not help a newbie recognize that the issue is `order`.  Stack Overflow is many things, but it is not a tutorial for learning languages.

Comment: They're similar in that all 3 results in endless duplication, which is bad (IMO). I'd rather comment saying `"'key' is a reserved word, which can't be used as a column name [or whatever]. See [link to canonical post]."` and vote to close as a duplicate (and eventually delete it) rather than posting an answer or not closing it at all.

Comment: @Dukeling . . . My answer is motivated by the fact that what you recommend doesn't happen.  I rarely see a comment specifying which word causes the problem (note:  that is part of what I recommend), and if I do, it is rarely from someone who voted to close. Merely saying that reserved words should be quoted doesn't necessarily help the OP figure out which one it is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is a comprehensive list of reserved words on [the MySQL site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) that a canonical answer would presumably reference though.

Comment: I think this answer (and it's down voting) sum up the real problem with this current fad of discussions about squashing duplicates.  If the OP understood enough to understand that the question that looks completely different is the same question, they would not be posting the question.  This jives with feedback from RL conversations that google hits to SO end up being useless because they are duplicates pointing to a question that looks nothing like the problem they were looking to solve.  Because an expert sees the connection does not mean it is a duplicate.

Comment: @tcaswell this goes both ways - just because someone who has absolutely no idea what he's doing doesn't see a connection doesn't mean it's not a duplicate. Just playing devils advocate, I guess we should create different canonical questions for the most commonly misused keywords, one for `KEY`, `ORDER`, etc? SO is for professional and enthusiast programmers. I'd say enthusiasts should be able to figure it out when presented with a well written answer, or at least arrive at a different and possibly better question. And if they really don't get it, a few comments should help them understand.

Comment: Nothing stops askers from editing their question to explain why the linked duplicate does not address their problem; nothing stops searchers from posting a question explaining the same, @tcaswell. "I have a problem that _looks_ like this one, but isn't the same because X, Y, and Z" is a _great_ question for SO to have.

Answer (score 4):

Until an [incentive is given for find duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions) nothing much will change.  **Unless** a few people that are arrive in the MySQL tag takes it on themselves to check all incoming MySQL questions and vote to close.

It also needs a few people that are active in the MySQL tag to filter the close queue down to MySQL and process all the queue close tasks, as otherwise the vote to close as a duplicate will not take effect for a long time.

We also need to decide what to do if the use of a reserved keyword is only part of the problem with the questioners SQL.

Answer (score 1):

No, not as a "as a typographical error", because it's not a "typo", it's simply not being "aware of" a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). The words `from` and `to`, `key` etc. are words that I doubt would be misspelled.

If someone can't spell those words, then the education that's been spent for it, has evidently failed and the system has failed them entirely.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error) states:

> A **typographical error** (often shortened to **typo**) is a mistake made in the typing process (such as spelling, misuse of tense or leaving out a word of printed material. Historically, this referred to mistakes in manual type-setting (typography). The term includes errors due to mechanical failure or slips of the hand or finger, but excludes errors of ignorance, such as spelling errors. Before the arrival of printing, the "copyist's mistake" or "scribal error" was the equivalent for manuscripts. Most typos involve simple duplication, omission, transposition, or substitution of a small number of characters.

Comment: Your point being? The Q&A pair is good or bad? Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to convey.

Comment: @AmalMurali What I'm trying to say is that many if not all new coders who get into SQL probably don't even know what a reserved word is, and I for one, fell into that category when I first started. Therefore, people will use reserved words without them even knowing and have no idea how to deal with it. More times than none, is the reason they come on SO posting their question then only being marked as duplicate.

Comment: I agree with that. This Meta question, however, asks "*What should we do with "MySQL reserved keywords" questions?*" — The general community consensus seems to be that they should be closed as a duplicate of a canonical question. I'm not sure if you're actually saying the Q&A pair is not useful, or that it is. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @AmalMurali Ok, I will edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: @AmalMurali I have edited my answer.

Comment: I actually went against my "no more answers" on this one, and I get downvoted; good one. Means s*it to me. This will indeed be **my ever last answer.** A "community" awright; ***yeah right.***

Comment: I have no idea what point you're trying to make with this answer.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot (Exactly) and I do and I believe I've made it quite clear. Whoever wants to downvote it (or upvote it for that matter), are free to do so. Means nothing to me. I think this so-called "community" has gone to the dogs. The answer stays.

Comment: Your point may be clear to you, but it isn't clear to myself or Amal. Can you explain your argument in one sentence?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The first two paragraphs speak for themselves. I have nothing further to add.

Comment: Re. "One cannot be expected to memorize them all" That's why Amal created a reference question that lists the most common MySQL reserved words and includes a link to the complete list. Do you disagree with that approach?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot No, not as a *"as a typographical error"*, because it's not a "typo", it's simply not being "aware of" a reserved word. The words "from" and "to", "key" etc. are words that I doubt would be mispelled. If someone can't spell those words, then the education (if any) that's been spent for it, has evidently failed and the system has failed them entirely. As Wikipedia states *"A typographical error is a mistake made in the typing process (such as spelling, misuse of tense or leaving out a word)[2] of printed material."*

Comment: Re. *No, not as a "as a typographical error", because it's not a "typo", it's simply not being "aware of" a reserved word.* Now *that* would have been a reasonable answer to the question. Amal originally proposed closing reserved word questions as typos, but if you read the comments on his post, you'll see that myself and others objected to that and recommended closing them as duplicates of a reference question instead. A number of questions have already been closed as dupes of the reference question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I guess I didn't fully understand the question then. Therefore, I will change my answer to just that then, in using my previous comment to you.

Comment: I agree with @Fred-ii-, as more people starts learning mysql there  will be daily questions on reserved keywords, unless there is a self explanatory error message from mysql about the use of reserved word in the query without back-ticks. However I have seen many such questions being closed by referring to an answer, and I am sure there are many newbie who would even find it difficult to understand it and lets accept, we even today while learning new things face the same. So my only point is to provide info to the questioner that error being happed due to this `keyword` and its reserved.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: You seem to have missed the point. The question was asking for suggestions on what should be done with these questions. I actually offer two ideas: 1. close as a typo, 2. create a canonical Q&A pair, and close these questions as a duplicate of that one. Your answer just says these are not typo, and doesn't actually offer any alternative suggestions. (I've now updated the question in an attempt to clarify further.)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: If the question about a syntax error caused due to using a reserved word as an identifier is closed as a duplicate of this one, the OP can easily read the answer and find out that the solution is to either not use the reserved word as an identifier at all, or to backtick-quote the identifier. I don't see how that's confusing. Personally, I feel that is a lot better than answering all the duplicates with the same kind of answer, over and over again.

Comment: @AmalMurali The thing is Amal, the ones who use reserved words without knowing, and who come to us about a problem, will not use nor will they know to use `"mysql" "is a reserved keyword"` in their query on Google (as you state in your question), because they basically have no idea why/what caused the problem in the first place. If they'd know, or know about reserved words, they are more likely not going to visit SO and post a question related to a reserved word related issue. Your question is just as vague as you claim my answer to be.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes, they are not aware of the issue at the time of posting. If they were, they wouldn't have posted it in the first place. The point is, we don't really want to repeat the same information again and again, in multiple answers to repeated questions (people will *never* stop asking these questions, I'm sure). Whether they know about it or not, the whole point is to not repeat information that is already available on the site. The search query, by the way, has nothing to do with the OP — it's just there to give an idea about the number of such questions on the site.

Comment: @AmalMurali The responsibility shouldn't rest on us and that's why we're here discussing this. The people who have put the StackOverflow system together should be the ones taking care of this matter. I don't see any of them doing anything about it and they're relying on us to do "their" work. As resource-intensive it stands to be, they could implement or try and come up with some form of algorithm to detect these possible duplicates and mark it as a duplicate automatically. I for one think that I shouldn't bear that burden of being the "big brother".

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Many similar ideas have been proposed in the past, and they've all been ignored. You can be like [this guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253411/1438393) and complain about the system not being perfect, or you can actually go ahead do *something* to help the situation, even if a little bit :)

Comment: @AmalMurali I believe I do my fair share of closing a question based on the situation as well as the choices provided by Stack. I feel that the choices they give us often does not fit into a particular category, and that's something I feel should also be addressed.