# New "reference questions"?

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical

This question:

[Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/why-cant-i-use-certain-words-as-table-column-names-in-mysql)

states this: "Note: This is a reference question. If you come across any questions matching this pattern, please close them as a duplicate of this one."

Is this an official "thing" or do we have some more defined way of doing things like this?  I don't know how I feel about trying to come up with new reference questions where we likely already have them.

Comment: No, this is not "official". The OP added that note to the question. I applaud wanting to make a canonical question/answer pair, which in general we do want.

Comment: I prefer to see answers on them posted as community wikis though since they are pretty much the definition of a CW.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I don't see much CW there.  It's a question-answer pair.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: definitely, but eventually it will grow into something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1864167). These all-compassing reference questions turn out to be something the community piles up additional information

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: If it turns into a "list of things," we can consider making it a collaborative question then.  But there's really only one good answer to that question.

Comment: This has to do with [What should we do with "MySQL reserved keywords" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253345)

Answer (score -9):

StackOverflow needs an official list of the questions that are officially considered reference material.