# How can I help a question to get reopened?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

I recently answered [this question on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23833525/659190)

Now, this question is about a trivial problem for an experienced TSQL developer, and can be fixed by changing one or two characters.

However, the question is well constructed, clearly states the problem and its symptoms. <s>Additionaly, it doesn't appear to be a duplicate</s>. It represents a real error, with a misleading symptom, that new TSQL developers make. It is not caused by mistyping on the keyboard.

The question has been "put on hold". Now, while I agree with the agressive closure of the myriad poorly considered, under researched and badly written questions that are posted every hour, rarely the inverse is true.

New questions attract a lot of attention, they are at the "top of the list". They can easily get the five votes they need to be "put on hold". Getting five votes to reopen a question seems to be much harder.

What can I do to attract attention to a question that I think has been inappropriately "put on hold"?

I've considered flagging it to a moderator but, I'm concerned this would be miscontrued, would that be appropriate?

Comment: The first step should be editing the question to improve it. Like *fixing the title*. That's a terrible title, it doesn't tell anyone what the problem is. It also wouldn't hurt to capitalize sentences.

Comment: @CodyGray, they were obvious points I should have picked up on.

Comment: Btw. does the golden badge superpower times three closing weight also counts for reopening votes?

Comment: @tri Yes, it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that any closed question you edit or vote-to-open will enter the [reopen-review-queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/182796), and will stay there until enough people have cast their vote to reopen it or keep it closed.  Anyone with the reputation required to cast close and reopen votes can see this queue, and many [do check it regularly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward)

That queue is usually almost empty, because those reviews happen quicker than new questions enter the queue.

So simply improving the question through edits should be enough to raise attention.

It *will* soon get the attention of at least 4 people that care enough to vote for it. People that just view the question and do not vote on it, will not cause it to disappear from the queue.

(Although the question may run into robo-reviewers that do not really care about the question and simply want their badge. Make sure that the reason for reopening is visible at first glance, and there are no obvious flaws for reviewers to latch onto)

If the first edit does not cause the question to be reopened, you can improve the question further to try again. The question will enter the review queue again, and get reviewed by different people. But keep in mind many people may primarily look at the new changes to decide if the question has improved enough, so pointlessly small edits should be avoided.

If you have some remarks about why the question should be reopened that do not really belong in the question body itself, leave those as a comment to the question. Reviewers see those comments too.

Comment: And, on that theme, I will more diligently address questions accessible in my reopen-review-queue.

Comment: _"any closed question you edit [...] will enter the [Re-open queue]..."_ Isn't that only true of questions that are in their 5-day "on hold" probationary period?

Comment: No, as far as I can tell "questions with active reopen votes, as well as questions which have been edited after closing, appear in the reopen queue". (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/182796)

Comment: Actually the documentation about this appears contradictory. http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions : "Any question that has received one reopen vote gets added to this queue, as well as any post edited within five days of the question's closure.". So I may be mistaken about the consequences of late edits.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you believe this is not a duplicate?

These "incorrect syntax near the keyword x" questions, with answer "x is a keyword and must be quoted" come up all the time.

In my opinion it is not really necessary to have a question for each possible value of x but there is already one for "table" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326007/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-table-error).

See also 
[What should we do with "MySQL reserved keywords" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253345/what-should-we-do-with-mysql-reserved-keywords-questions)

Comment: I no longer believe its not a duplicate.

Comment: I've suppressed my rep-whoredom but I can't find the canonical answer. I've marked the latter as a duplicate of the earlier you identified.

Comment: @Jodrell Maybe would be better to try and make your answer as canonical/generic as possible (e.g. With link to SQL Server reserved words list) and do the closure the other way round.

Comment: I've had a go at making it canonical.

Comment: @Jodrell *"I no longer believe its not a duplicate."*... Does that mean that you believe that it *is* a duplicate?

Comment: @JL2210, let me think back 5 years, erm, It means that I retract my previous assertion.

Answer (score 1):

**Improve the quality of the question.**

1. Ensure that the question Title accurately represents the issue to be addressed.
2. Fix spelling, punctuation, grammar and capitalization errors in the question.
3. Correct the Tags assigned to the question.
4. ...

Comment: I just casted the final reopen vote. The question is open now.