# I have an answer to this closed question

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have an answer to the following question: [UITableView scroll indicator won't hide at top or bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111397/uitableview-scrollbar-doesnt-hide). Because I had exactly the same problem, but that question is closed.

I edited the question to make it a lot more readable, but now I would like it to be reopened so that I can answer it. Or should I just make a new question?

I think I could also supply the code to reproduce the problem in the question, but can I add code to reproduce a problem in a question that was not originally my question?

UPDATE:
Ok I see what I should do next, according to the other question [How can I help a question to get reopened?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256445/how-can-i-help-a-question-to-get-reopened), I should add code to the question and probably change the title of the question.

This seems like a lot more of an extreme change if you compare it to the other question. Also the other question was mentioned as a 'beginner' question although considered legitimate by the meta-poster. This question however is more intermediate with my answer being a bit of a hack. I don't see how the question I'm asking now can be considered a duplicate, but it is just fascinating that the answer is the same.

So the question is, considering the specific question I'm trying to reopen, is it ok to add code to it even thought it's not my original question?

Comment: Yes - but make 100% sure that your own code shows the exact problem that this (rather badly stated) question is about. The OP is quite sparse with the details so I wonder if you actually can be sure.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence of your edit, and I can't figure out how to edit it.  *"I had this problem by setting the view controller setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` (Which I needed)."*  What does that even mean?  And speaking in the first person in an edit of someone else's post is not a good idea--it appears you are putting your words in someone else's mouth.  I'd strongly suggest you re-edit to make your changes into just **step by step instructions on how to reproduce the issue**.  It appears you're doing that, but that bit at the top is way confusing.

Comment: I took out the first person part now, hopefully the question can be reopened soon. thanks @Will

Comment: Much better, thanks!  I VTR as well.

Comment: There you go, it's reopened. The OP is still active on SO, let us hope he agrees with your additions.