# What should I do when I have an answer to a closed question?

Tags: support, answers, closed-questions

I think this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256445/how-can-i-help-a-question-to-get-reopened), because in that question the asker has already answered and wants the question he answered to be reopened.

What I want is for [the question I want to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65255398/how-do-i-convert-this-math-equation-into-c-program) to be reopened so I can answer it.

---

I saw a question that I knew how to solve, so I started making an answer.  While I was making the answer, I noticed that the question was gaining donwnvotes (like 4 or 5 of them).  When I finished writing my answer, I saw that the question had gotten closed as unfocused minutes before I was able to post my answer.  I am not a gold-badge holder, ♦ moderator, or any sort of special user on Stack Overflow.  I do not (at the time of writing) have enough reputation to cast close/reopen votes (3000 rep. if anyone wants to know).

So what should I do?

Comment: Depends on the question. Such a bad reception sounds like an indicator that the question is horribly off-topic or has no chance of being of use to others in the future - in which case, best to not do anything. But if you truly think future programmers would benefit from being able to look up the question and your answer, can you post a link to the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I help a question to get reopened?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256445/how-can-i-help-a-question-to-get-reopened)

Comment: If you disagree with the closing, you can post a meta question stating why you think the question shouldn't be closed. Otherwise: Focus on on-topic questions. Answering off-topic ones is not going to work out. Just to clarify: Beeing able to answer a questions doesn't necessarily mean that the question is on-topic.

Comment: @BDL : I guess that is true.  My point of asking this question is that it took some effort to write the answer ([Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65255398/how-do-i-convert-this-math-equation-into-c-program)).  I wrote out the whole entire equation and I do not think it is a good idea to do so much effort for a question that will get closed.

Comment: Do you think the question is on-topic and should be reopened?  That you "knew how to solve" is not enough of to ascertain the question is actually fit for this site.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj This seems like a pretty clearly bad question. Instead of putting effort into getting it reopenned and answering it, try to understand why it was poorly received.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj It's a good idea to try to familiarize yourself with what's on-topic for Stack Overflow, so you're less likely to have that problem in the first place.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj: You are completely right: Investing a lot of time in off-topic questions is not a good idea. That's why you should focus on questions that are on-topic on SO. The question shows zero effort, doesn't state with which part op has problems with. SO is not a code writing service, it is a q&a site for **specific** programming problems. The tooltip of the down-vote button "does not show any research effort" is a perfect match for this kind of questions.

Comment: It's good that you might learn something when trying to answer some questions on here, but after reading the linked question... yeah, there's no way to salvage that question. We don't even know what that equation is for, it's not going to help anyone else other than the asker, which is not really the goal of Stack Overflow...

Comment: It turns out that the question wasn’t just closed. It was deleted “for reasons of moderation”. Why?

Comment: @Brian Closed questions are susceptible of being deleted. They can be automatically deleted, or other users with enough reputation can cast "delete votes" if they feel the question cannot be redeemed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always reformulate the question as a new post and answer that.

Take a look at the question and see if you can understand why others would consider it unclear or unfocused.  Then you can write a new question based on that one while addressing the shortcomings of the original question, i.e. provide details where the original is lacking, try to concentrate on a single issue, etc.

Once you've done this, you can post the new question and self-answer it.  It would also be a good idea to link back to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to all of you who have answered this question in comments.

**A note to people who arrive at this question for the same reason: If the question is gaining downvotes, don't answer it.  The Stack Overflow community will close the question and all of your progress and time will be wasted.**

In conclusion: do not use up your time on questions that are likely to get downvotes ***no matter how easy they seem to answer***.  Because if they seem likely to get downvotes, they will be likely to be closed and your effort will go in vain.

Comment: Effectively, "ease of answering" is not a topicality factor.

Comment: @yivi in fact, "easy to answer" questions are quite likely to be duplicates already. Not necessarily, of course, but something to watch out for.

Comment: Worse, a poorly posed question may be a set-up for help vampirism, deliberate or accidentally. You solve the obvious problem, but there's a less obvious problem. Or you've fixed the problem but it STILL doesn't work because of problems left out of the question. Or the asker wound up in their nightmarish current situation because they lack the fundamentals to be able to understand the answer you gave. Answering a question can be a tough business.

Comment: Note that sometimes a question is not gaining downvotes, it could even be well-asked, *but it has already been asked and answered many times before*, which makes it a duplicate, and duplicate questions [are one of the reasons a question is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Rather than answering to repeat existing answers, it's better to just close it as a duplicate.