# Posting an intentionally too broad/unclear catch-all question

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical, needs-more-focus

Imagine that someone is putting great effort into writing a "catch-all" question with answers for a certain topic.

The answers mostly already exist in one form or another, but this question is meant to be an intentionally "too broad / unclear" question so that it can be used for canonically closing any question that may ask one aspect or another in the broad topic.

Instead of arguing with people  on Stack Overflow whether or not it is good a direction, I would like to hear what you guys think about it.

I will not share my opinion about it to stay neutral and not lead the opinions that may come. I would like to sincerely hear what the community thinks.

Let us imagine a topic like this:

> Importing some library into some C++ project using some IDE with some build system on some operating system and architecture with some compiler and version.

Then, the OP would expect to get many small answers in one thread, basically replicating the existing and modularized threads to be a catch-all and canonical thread.

As you can see it is intentionally a very broad topic. Naturally, I have my own opinion about it and pro/cons, but I would hold it off for a second.

Please note that this is not about any existing case, just a general strategy question on Stack Overflow whether get such "too broad / unclear" and "catch-all" questions.

Comment: Well... *some* context is required.  We can't broadly say whether or not it's okay until we pin down what the actual context of the intentionally broad question is.

Comment: @Makoto: the context is solving a "general issue", `Importing some library into some C++ project using some IDE with some build system on some operating system and architecture with some compiler and version.` and there might be many answers and/or sections covering each aspect that needs to be handled separately. For example, qmake buildsystem is one section/answer, cmake another, foo IDE is another, and bar IDE is yet another, etc.

Comment: As that reads, it's way too broad, and unless the answer itself is redeeming enough, then I would feel that such a self-answered question wouldn't be appropriate as "canonical".  You said it yourself - there may be many other answers covering each aspect that need to be treated separately.

Comment: Is this question intentionally ironic?  It's apparently an intentionally vague question about intentionally vague questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I can assure you that I meant to write a clear question here. Could you please explain it what you miss so that I can update the question to be less vague?

Comment: I tried to do a write-up on the CW process in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252046/578411). Without knowing the details it looks at least like step 1, 2 and 3 have been skipped...

Comment: @rene: thanks for the list, having that read makes me feel 4-6, too. I also suggested the CW earlier, but that has been refused, so I imagine the OP did not mean it as CW material.

Comment: @FinalContest CW *is not* needed. [Please see Anna's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253345/what-should-we-do-with-mysql-reserved-keywords-questions#comment15438_253345).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I am confused about your previous post. You say that is unclear a question, and then you answer it without asking for clarification. You just did not get it at first? Is your comment obsolete now?

Comment: @hichris123: it is not a reputation related discussion.

Comment: @Raedwald Both questions were flagged as a duplicate of the other one (in fact... you flagged Final Contest question, and he flagged yours). Would be better to close yours and redirect everything here, as there're already several upvoted answers.

Comment: @Raedwald: this post has an answer, the other does not.

Comment: +1 I am not sure what is unclear. I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 20):

For a read on canonical questions and how they're supposed to work, check out:

> [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

and

> [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Both of these questions have what I consider ideal characteristics for canonical questions.  They both:

1. Address a problem that's commonly asked by users who don't do prior research,
2. Have definitive answers that fully address the specific problem,
3. Can be easily located in a Google Search.

Canonical questions, by their very nature, are always going to seem too broad to some folks, because they have to *address specific problems in the general case.*

*How do I do this thing* questions are always going to seem broad to some folks, because they still want to know "what have you tried?"  But that doesn't necessarily make them bad questions.  They are bad questions if they require a book chapter to answer, or have too many correct answers.

Comment: By broken down parts, do you mean [this barrage of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent) (other than the first two)?

Comment: My worry is that it might be less effective to find an answer to the point if we start closing every single question in a broad topic that is answered as a canonical duplicate that does not actually give a solution for that particular problem, just some basic knowledge. It is valuable, I agree, but might not be the best option. If we are to replicate the existing broken-down parts (yes, what you showed, thanks), we need to find the gist in a huge thread. I come across such closed questions frequently in the C++ tag, where the issue is not the generic part, but some specific thing.

Comment: Not every topic lends itself to canonical questions, but many do.  The problem with canonical questions is that 1.  They're difficult to do well, and 2. They tend to be controversial, because they are intentionally broad by design.

Comment: Yes, those are my concerns. I appreciate the willingness to write canonical questions, but at this point I am not sure if they are more helpful than harmful, given that they already exist in broken-down parts.

Comment: In the absence of a canonical question, the dupe needs to be a *very close cousin* of the original.  **Good:** "Question is essentially the same, and a decent answer can be found over here, so close as dupe."  **Bad:** "Your answer can be found over here, so close as dupe."  Canonical questions, if done properly, can be used to more often say "Your answer is over here," but the bar is pretty high for such questions.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't that Good/Bad opinion speak up against the intentionally too-broad canonical duplicates? Another thing to be food for thought: cannot OPs defend themselves, including newcomers, that their question is intentionally too-broad if we allow intentionally too-broad canonical attempts? They could just as well say that "hey, it is meant to be a canonical". I understand and appreciate that it might not be the same, but it might.

Comment: It's not too broad if it can be definitively answered in the space of an answer box.  Neither of the two questions I cited are too broad.  They could stand quite happily on their own, even if they weren't canonical questions.  That's what the community doesn't always understand: not every question needs to be a highly-localized troubleshooting question.

Comment: OK, maybe your example is not in the same range as the aforementioned C++ one. There are different factors in that case which may occur in pretty much any combination, which makes it a question astronaut, to me. Where to draw the line? There will be opinions forth and back, who will say the final word? We do not have a tag maintainer on Stack Overflow as far as I know.

Comment: I wouldn't know. I don't know which question you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, I see the question now.  It does seem a bit broad, but it doesn't have much negative backlash.  You might need one answer per IDE, but that's still a bounded set; I've seen the Unix and Linux site use this technique effectively to address different flavors of Linux.  Also, Stack Overflow is a bit of an oddball in the SE network; questions like [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/986/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-vim-and-emacs) would never fly here.

Comment: Well, as a professional C++ developer for years and active participant to the tag in question having answered many of those questions in that range, I can say that, that question will duplicate at least 20-30 existing modularized threads. Re previous discussion, do you define your aforementioned questions too-broad in the end of the day?

Comment: Robert, it is not only about IDE. If you re-read it, you can see there are at least 5-6 moving factors in pretty much any combination. I bet if you wish to answer that all, you end up having 100+ answers or more, which we already have, mostly, with the difference of proper modularization, not having to need to read through a lot of irrelevant material.

Comment: As I see it: the point is that the person asking the question "artificially" can afford that breadth, because that person *knows the answer*, and therefore knows that the general case *is a general case of the same thing*, and therefore that it the question isn't as broad as it looks: the same idea is applicable to multiple specific situations, and things that seem to matter don't actually.

Answer (score 7):

> I have just noticed that someone is putting great effort into writing
>   a "catch-all" question with answers for a certain topic.
>   The answers mostly already exist in one form or another, but this

You are describing [canonical questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=canonical+question) ([Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/search?q=canonical+question) has discussed them at more length). Canonical questions are Stack Exchange's FAQs.

It happens often that small variants of the same question get asked over and over again. Usually, many of these variants have minor variations involving side issues that are irrelevant to solving the problem. Answerers end up rehashing the same thing over and over again, with just minor details.

The point of a canonical question is to provide a single point of entry covering the basics. They serve two purposes:

- Many questions can be closed as duplicates of the canonical question, when the underlying issue is obvious enough.
- Even when the underlying issue takes a bit of investigation, questions about related issues can be answered with a brief explanation of the investigation to take, and refer to the canonical question for a detailed explanation.

> question is meant to be an intentionally "too broad / unclear"

You are apparently conflating two things: *broad* and *unclear*. Unclear questions should be closed, but it's rare for attempts at making a canonical question to be unclear — usually they're posted by someone who has been answering dozens if not hundreds of similar questions and they have a good idea what to write.

Canonical questions are inherently broad; they attempt to cover the 90% common case. The proof of a broad question is in the answer: can someone write a good answer that really answers the question satisfactorily? If so the question isn't too broad. Sometimes we close questions as too broad because while it would be possible to provide an answer in 30000 characters (the answer size limit), we don't expect that anybody will bother to do that for a highly specific problem (essentially doing the asker's job). This doesn't apply to canonical questions, where the point is to write a reference answer that will help a lot of people.

> question so that it can be used for canonically closing any question
>   that may ask one aspect or another in the broad topic.

Yes, that's the whole point.

Comment: `Canonical questions are inherently broad; they attempt to cover the 90% common case` -> certainly not. I would say most of the time they are actually inherently not too broad so there can be no hijacking that "this question answers much more than I need". There are many simple and to the point canonicals  that we regularly use to close that type of question as duplicate. This happens daily in the given tag.

Comment: @FinalContest I don't frequest the [tag:c++] tag (that's the tag you're talking about, right?), but if you never have broad canonical questions, you're underusing them. You should strive to have more such reference questions instead of rehashing the same stuff over and over again. Yes, it does hurt if a canonical question is too broad, but the proof of that is in the answer. If it's possible to write a well-organized answer that covers what people need to know, then the question isn't *too* broad. “Broad” ≠ “too broad”.

Comment: Well, we can agree about that the question should not be too broad, but it is intentionally too broad and poor question (even stated so by the OP by the way ;)), so the point here is that there are several moving targets in various combination. I cannot possibly imagine to answer that on one Stack Overflow page or even two.

Comment: `it seeks to cover a common issue and the answer manages reasonably well` -> It actually misses a lot of scenarios which can be read in comments as critics from C++ experts (not only me).. That is, people with gold and silver badges in the tag. I think many C++ experts would agree that it is close to impossible to cover every scenario that short.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why did you delete that paragraph? Discussing these issues without a concrete example is sterile.

Answer (score 5):

The subject matter to me appears to be overly broad in and of itself.  Since C++ has many different platforms, compilers, and far more IDEs, I'm not convinced that such a self-answered question could be *complete*, let alone canonical.

Although to be blunt, that's not what's bothering me.  What's bothering me is that the question itself was made to be *intentionally* too broad.

I'm not necessarily thrilled that the question is overly broad and the answer tries to pin down several different things at once - it seems to me that smaller questions and answers focused to the platform or the IDE alone would make more sense.

Then again, I'm not a C++ guy; I'm only giving my take on the matter.  I'm not *thrilled*, but since I don't know enough about the subject material, I'm not going to jump immediately into the situation.

Comment: +1 for your opinion. I am a C++ gold badge holder at least and doing C++ professionally... I wonder if I shall submit my answer, too.... I think it would be more fair if I stay away from that.

Comment: _'Then again, I'm not a C++ guy'_ For c++ it's a quite recurring pattern, with only small variations regarding the various mentioned IDE's.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: no, there are many C++ IDEs (Visual Studio, Eclipse, QtCreator, KDevelop, Code Blocks, etc), various build system (qmake, cmake, automate, Makefiles, ninja, scon, etc), various compilers (gcc, mingw, msvc, clang, TI compiler, etc), various versions of it, various platforms (Linux, Mac, Windows, Android, ios, blackberry, QNX, etc), various architectures (x86, x86_64, x32), and I could enumerate. Any combination can occur, but then again these have already been answered.

Comment: @FinalContest And it will always boil down to the actual underlying toolchain setting for include/library searchpath's, so what?!? Provide an appropriate dupe for the question. if you have one.

Comment: No, it will not; when you use an IDE, it is possible to set it up with IDE specific helper UI, but even if it was, you eliminated one factor out of the rest which is still too many.

Comment: @FinalContest May be a point of being able to get and extract _abstractions_ from an actual use case ...

Comment: @FinalContest _'I am a C++ gold badge holder'_ You are so _shiny_! All of the puns intended :D ...