# Is it eligible to post a question that contains informative links regarding a topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, canonical

I was searching for the last few hours for the best practices for managing lists in Python but I couldn't find a single resource that contains all beneficial information about lists.

However, SO contains hundreds of good and beneficial questions on Python lists but they're dispersed. So, I thought I could maybe combine and post them with the title "Python lists best practices" for development by the community. But, I do not know what would be the consequences of that since [Stack Overflow - How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says that I should have a question, not an informative post.

I am not trying to make a blog-like post, just combining questions regarding a topic into one post.

Comment: @gnat Sorry, but I do not notice how is that even related?

Comment: The more common answer to these kind of situations is to write a [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265500/posting-an-intentionally-too-broad-unclear-catch-all-question). That is however easier said than done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you shouldn't post that as a question. As you say, that's not a question. So it wouldn't make sense to post it as a question.

If it's not a question, no answers can be post. Not very practical for a Question & Answer site.

The consequences would be that a question like that is likely to be closed and/or downvoted; and finally deleted.

And you shouldn't post *a question to post that as an answer to*, because that question would be off-topic for the site.

Kudos to you for reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You shoud also read about what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on the site (if you haven't yet).