# Is it OK to create a question for the sole purpose of having a community wiki?

Tags: discussion

I created [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787306/what-are-some-low-level-optimizations-that-could-be-performed-in-c-to-increase) question on SO because I wanted to have a place where information about low-level optimizations could be gathered, as I didn't find and other place like that.

The question itself was supposed to be only symbolic, letting people know what the post is about. The important part was supposed to be the community wiki with a collection of different methods of low-level optimizations.

And so it got closed... Apparently the question was considered *"too broad"* and closed. Is it OK to ask questions in such format and with such purpose as described here?

P.S. I modified the question, so now it should be less broad.

Comment: I would agree that your question on main is too broad as it stands. General information about some tag would usually belong in its tag wiki. Granted, those suffer from poor discoverability.

Comment: Related: [*Posting an intentionally too broad/unclear catch-all question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265500/2751851); [*How to improve a canonical question, that may appear to be “too broad”?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364906/2751851) (the latter includes [my strongly opinionated take](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364947/2751851) on the general issue).

Comment: Note: making a question community wiki does *not* make it immune to regular moderator processes.  It's not a get out of closure free card.

Comment: "This post is meant to organize a lot of different kinds of optimizations in one place" Sounds like you're *admitting* you know it's too broad, and are not actually trying to answer a specific question.

Comment: I think that it depends a little on what the question is. In the early days of the site, people used to use the CW feature as a "free pass" to post extremely subjective questions and polls. (I actually saw a recent case where someone suggested in the comments that the question should be made a Community Wiki to prevent it from being closed as Subjective and Argumentative). I'm not sure exactly where to draw the line on what is - and isn't - acceptable though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is not only okay to create a Question+Answer for the purpose of creating a Community Wiki, but in fact it should be encouraged, and my interpretation of several posts/blogs on the topic is that it was, in fact, a key part of [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)'s early vision for the site.

The most obvious evidence that it's encouraged as part of normal use of the site is that ***it is an option*** even when answering your own question:

[image: img]

...if SO's [creators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#History) intended to discourage it from happening, then presumably they wouldn't have made it an option when asking+answering a question at the same time.

The next obvious question is ***"Is it okay to answer your own question?"***, but that has already been answered many times, including [by Atwood himself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/):

> - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
> - if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
> - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.
>
> To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is *explicitly encouraged***.

Therefore the next logical step is, if you feel it is information that will benefit [at least some of] the community and it would best if it was maintained by a wider group of users.

---

**From [*"Putting the Community back in Wiki"*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/22/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/):**

> **An author can still apply the status manually when posting or when editing their own answer**, and moderators retain the ability to apply it when they deem it truly necessary ... For the most part, we’ve turned it back into something that *you can choose to use in cases where it lets you **work together to create something wonderful**:*
>
> - Compiling a canonical reference
> - Consolidating the knowledge of the community
> - Encouraging the ongoing, active maintenance of a changing answer

Even more evidence that this it is beneficial to the community for someone to create a question with the intention of being a Community Wiki, is the fact that, by doing so, you're giving up any "personal advantage" of potential reputation gain, etc.

[image: img]

---

**Also, consider:** *(Source: **[Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) > [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) > [Create Wiki Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)**)*

> **When should I make my answers Community Wiki?**
>
> - When you want to enhance the "wiki" aspect of your post, so that it can be a continually evolving source of good information through repeated editing.
> - When you feel your post would benefit from less concern about voting affecting the reputation of those participating in it.

The fact is that, like any action someone takes on SO, if you think that particular post should not have been posted as a Wiki, just contact a moderator, as [only] they have the ability to remove the "Wiki" status, and I'm sure they'll collectively make the right decision.

...so really, there's nothing to lose, and lots of potential benefits.

---

I'm not saying that any Q+A is suitable to be a Community Wiki, and some general guidelines are to be followed, such as these points (explained further [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/)):

- Community Wiki is not for Fun
- Community Wiki is not a “Quick Fix”
- Community Wiki is primarily for Answers
- Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly.

---

You'll find more info about Community Wiki's in this Community Wiki:
**[*"What are “Community Wiki” posts?"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/370758)**

Comment: I fully agree with you. When I created that question *this* was my exact intent. That’s why I was so surprised that my question got closed. I thought that people would appreciate the amount of information and effort put into this post.

Comment: I think that questions shouldn’t be closed just because “they don’t fit the rules”. It should be about the content, not formalism. How would I be supposed to present a “minimal reproductible example” in such type of a question.

Comment: I think the current format strongly discourages making general, but still very useful and valuable questions. If someone can make a single general question instead of a dozen other, less broad questions, he should not only be not punished, but also encouraged to do so, as it saves a lot of people’s time and organises knowledge in one place in such a manner that it can be easily edited and improved by the community.

Comment: This answer is completely correct in all its points, yet fails to address the specific situation called out in this specific meta question, which is, can I ask off-topic questions solely for the purpose of making a Community Wiki answer..

Comment: @Yan B. Re _questions shouldn’t be closed just because “they don’t fit the rules”_, that is _exactly_ why they should be closed. From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): _"To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question"_. An interesting question with a good answer isn't automatically valid on SO.

Comment: I know, but in my opinion it should

Comment: @YanB. If not to comply with the rules, then why should any question ever be closed? And yes, the current format of the site and its rules *do* discourage general questions. This isn't a site for general questions. It's a site for *specific*, *answerable* questions so people know what they're getting when they open one an dread the content. The verbiage somewhere that says "if you feel your content is substantive enough to exist as a good blog post, then it's probably too broad/long for Stack Overflow".

Comment: @YanB. Users do appreciate that kind of question--a LOT.  thanks for trying.  It's been my favorite type of questions and the ones I learn the most from and the ones that I'm happiest to come across.  Moderators aren't generally coming at this from the same POV as users I guess.

Answer (score 36):

While I appreciate the intent, this isn't really what Stack Overflow is for. You're trying to create a grab-bag of information, a central clearing house of random tips. SO prefers focused problems with specific solutions because that's what a search engine can look for. People look for problems, not random tips. That's why FAQs don't work; they're not indexed properly in search engines, so users who need them won't be able to find them.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misunderstood what "community wiki" means for a Stack Overflow post. I don't blame you; it's very different from anything else you may have seen called a "wiki". The UX could use some improvement.

A Stack Overflow post marked "community wiki" is not like Wikipedia or like the wikis you may have seen hosted on sites like Fandom or other wiki hosts. It is not meant to be a comprehensive knowledgebase containing articles within some broad scope.

A community wiki question or answer is still a regular Stack Overflow question or answer, held to all the normal standards of its category of post. The only differences are that it has a lower reputation threshold for accepting unreviewed edits, it does not confer reputation on its poster, and answers to community wiki questions are automatically community wiki. It's called "community wiki" because of the collaborative editing and focus on community instead of individual ownership, not because of any sort of loosened restrictions on a question's scope.

If you want to make a wiki in the sense you were expecting, Stack Overflow is not the place to do it.