# Is it OK to ask for moderation intervention to reopen my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I created [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787306/what-are-some-low-level-optimizations-that-could-be-performed-in-c-to-increase) question on SO. It got closed as "too broad". Now I edited it and I think that it is no more "too broad". Is it OK to ask for moderator intervention to ask for reopening of my question apart ffrom just voting via "reopen"?

Comment: If you vote to reopen it will go into the reopen queue.  What makes this question so special that moderator intervention is necessary to subvert this process? Why can't the community of reopen queue voters handle it?

Comment: @RobertLongson I have the feeling that people won't want to click on the question because they will think it is bad because it is marked as "too broad". So nobody will vote to reopen.

Comment: Do you have evidence that the reopen queue voters don't reopen questions that have been narrowed from too broad to on-topic? Or do you worry that the question is really still too broad and the reopen voters will notice that and correctly vote not to reopen? If it's the latter then narrow the question further.

Comment: @YanB. They don't have to click on your question, that's the point of the queue. People go there specifically to review contested closures.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think that I misunderstood how the reopening works. I wasn't aware of the reopen queue.

Comment: FYI that looks like a [shopping list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/248731) (or "list of things" question), hence definitely too broad. You certainly shouldn't be asking for intervention until [you find out if it's OK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386527/3001761).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, as you should generally not assume that the moderator who handles your flag has domain knowledge. I could, for instance, in many cases not judge if some JavaScript question is too broad or not as I know nothing about the tech.

Instead, editing the question as you did puts it in a review queue where domain experts can vote on re-opening or leaving it closed. This review process has not yet completed for your question.

Answer (score 6):

No. Do not use moderator flags for asking to reopen questions that were closed by the community. The reopen queue is present just for this purpose.

That said, if a moderator has closed your question, then feel free to flag it for moderator intervention. From [the help page on reopening](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions):

> If a moderator (user with a ♦ symbol after their name) closed the question, then you may flag it for moderator attention. Again, do this only after editing and include a detailed explanation of why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions.