# Can we change the rules for posting duplicate answers / marking questions as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-undelete

I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2. I started to give a lot of answers for [pypdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pypdf) / [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)+[pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf) as I gained quite a lot of knowledge in this area recently. pypdf/PyPDF2 wasn't maintained for a while, which means that lots of people were stumbling over the same issues. That also means that my answers are identical / look very similar. Simply because the root-cause of the questions is the same.

Once I see this, I typically try to improve one question/answer and mark all other questions as duplicates.

However, I recently seen the situation where there was no question with an answer. There were several questions with the same cause. As no question had an answer, I could not mark any of those as duplicates:

[image]

So I did the second-best thing I could think of: Add the same answer to multiple questions. However, then that answer was deleted.

I would propose to not do that. Now we have a question that has no answers, although there was a perfectly fine one.

Alternatively, I propose to remove this rule that a question A cannot be closed as duplicate of another question B, if B has no upvoted answer.

### Duplicate answer, very different question

That is a similar phenomenon I've encountered. Quite often, I basically need to tell users to update PyPDF2 / pypdf, because their problem (the bug) was solved in the past years. Some of those questions are open for many years. As the maintainer, I know that this is the best answer. I also don't have the capacity to go more into detail - if people are curious what exactly was the issue / how it was solved, they should dive into the changelog.

That means for many questions my answer is: "Please update pypdf"

But the questions are very different. They are not duplicates.

If the community decides that deleting those answers is the best thing to do, I will simply not put any effort in adding the answers in the first place. Please tell me that this is not how you want Stack Overflow to work.

### Specific example:

- [How can extract just the visible text from a PDF, ignoring cropped parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19109465/562769) - here my answer was deleted
- [Cropped PDF still contains the original text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72804653/562769) - what I guess why it was closed
- [Extract text from pdf ignoring cropped content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49246504/562769) - another one that would deserve the same answer as the ones above

Comment: Suboptimal solution for the questions that really are duplicates: Post an answer on one of them, wait to get an upvote, and then mark the others as duplicates. (it's not, admittedly, a great solution)

Comment: For the ones that are just "update PyPDF", perhaps you could point to the specific fix in each answer.  That would make them non-duplicate answers that are tailored to the question.

Comment: "perhaps you could point to the specific fix in each answer" - that is not going to happen. This would simply drain an unacceptable amount of energy for an answer that likely nobody will ever read. People typically just want to see the solution. If they are actually interested in the root cause, they can dive into the changelog / the git history.

Comment: Also, most of the pypdf / PyPDF2 questions are clearly written by programming beginners. They would not be interested in the very specific issues around text extraction from PDF documents, where you have to dive deep into the PDF standard.

Comment: Fair.  You should specify at least a specific version that has the fix, but then you'd still run the risk of duplicates among bugs that were fixed in the same version...which, of course, are not duplicate _questions_, they just happen to be fixed by the same upgrade.

Comment: The problem that removal of duplicate answers is intended to solve is people copy-pasting indiscriminately (often to questions where the answer really does not apply), which is not what you're talking about doing here (I'm assuming you're not considering _literally_ just copy-pasting a "Please update pypdf" answer between all questions that can be solved by upgrading).  Unfortunately, the two can look similar at a glance. It would be good if we could come up with a clear dividing line between the two.

Comment: *"Please update pypdf"* is not an answer. You need to say exactly what the problem was an which version contains the fix.

Comment: *"are clearly written by programming beginners"* The person who wrote the question is not the primary audience. Don't focus on them.

Comment: You probably have some issues opened on GitHub for those bugs right? Add an answer stating it is a bug in the package having issue #PQR and is solved in version XYZ. If you have more time you could then add workarounds, etc. as needed.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the solution to "There's n questions and none are answered so i can't dupe close them" is "answer all of them" rather than "answer one of them and dupe close".

Comment: @KevinB Well, you can't unless someone upvotes or accepts your answer.  Which is, arguably, an unhelpful restriction.  I'd upvote a request to get rid of it (does anyone know of one?).

Comment: @Dharman '"Please update pypdf" is not an answer. ' - why not? It solves the problem. The problem was a bug/shortcomming of the library.

Comment: @RyanM This question is my request to get rid of that restriction :-)

Comment: @Dharman: "The person who wrote the question is not the primary audience. Don't focus on them." - why not? A lot of the questions around pypdf are the result of people not looking into existing issues on Github / understanding the issue the library has / understanding how PDF data extraction works. Often not even directly related to pypdf, but to working with Python in general (e.g. virtual environments). Those questions will likely only be of interest to beginners. Focusing the style of answer on the type of question asked is exactly the right thing to do, IMO.

Comment: @MartinThoma for feature requests, we generally want a focused [feature-request]-tagged question for easy escalation to staff.  It's hard to escalate a discussion with multiple alternative suggestions, as it's not clear which suggestions people are voting (both up and down) for.

Comment: Should I create a new question on meta focusing on that suggestion?

Comment: I would also be fine with somebody editing my question to focus on that part.

Comment: "That also means that my answers are identical ..." - If you are submitting the same solution to multiple questions, you should be voting to close those additional questions, leaving one high quality answer to rule them all. 'This question is my request to get rid of that restriction" - Is it? If so then this belongs on Meta Stack Exchange, since that type of change, would impact the entire community. This question is currently marked as a discussion, and what I see and based on the comments, most individuals are treating this question as a complaint with a "working as designed"

Comment: Question A "pypdf error: encryption algorithm not supported", question B: "pypdf error: wrong whitespace in text extraction". Solution to both: upgrade to pypdf>= 3.4.0. You really suggest to close one as a duplicate of the other?

Comment: "The person who wrote the question is not the primary audience. Don't focus on them." Because the site goal is to be a repository of good questions for others to find. Not a help desk. If you want to offer your users a help desk this is not the place to do it in any way that is not in keeping with the site. [tour] [help]

Answer (score 11):

I don't have a solution for this particular case, but it's just *not* possible to allow people to copy/paste the same answer to several questions.

It happens *all the time*, and it's a nuisance to the site. Most of the time:

- the questions are duplicates, OR
- the answer isn't tailored to the question.

There are rules against that. We can't just make an exception for that particular case. Besides, in a case like that where people choose to report the bug on Stack Overflow rather than on your GitHub page (it's a small project compared to GCC or other monsters, certainly that the author can help) the first thing to do should be to *update* their version, see if it fixes their issues.

If bugs are fixed in a new version, and you don't have/don't want to provide a workaround for the bug that you can propose without having to upgrade (which is always interesting),

**Why not just comment about the new version which fixes the issue?**

Okay, you're not getting reputation from that, but after a few years/months, the fact that there was a bug and it was then fixed brings nothing of value to the site (it's also the case for major software product like GCC or Python).

Commenting, on the other hand, helps users who forgot to upgrade.

Comment: If it solves the problem, it's an answer. Hence I want to post it as an answer. If the StackExchange community thinks it's not solving an issue, I will not bother to comment. If the question doesn't bring value to the site, can we just delete it?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions/answers around pypdf which use deprecated classes/methods. People see & copy those parts and ask questions around the deprecated stuff. Removing those unanswered questions that are resolved by just updating the library would be an overall benefit to the Python / pypdf / PyPDF2 community.

Comment: I fully agree. Maybe flag those posts so they can be deleted instead of them misleading people?

Comment: @MartinThoma If they are using deprecated methods or classes, you can say that in the answer. The method X in class Y is deprecated, use Z available in the current version instead. Just saying update the library is not the right way.

Comment: The issue is often that the library had a bug. I don't want to waste my time looking details of the bug up. I would be willing to let people know that this was fixed + doing an update of the library version does the trick. I'm not willing to waste more energy on this. Obviously the StackOverflow community prefers rather no answer than a helpful 95% answer 

Answer (score 10):

### Explaining a common root cause for multiple issues

> However, I recently seen the situation where there was no question with an answer. There were several questions with the same cause. As no question had an answer, I could not mark any of those as duplicates

Here is what to do for these cases:

1. Ask the best possible version of that question that you can (since, presumably, none of the ones you're finding are particularly well asked; if there *is* a well-asked version of the question - something clear and explicit, with a proper [mre], that accurately identifies the root cause - then use that instead).
2. Answer it yourself, as best you can, which [is in accordance with policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).
3. Wait for someone to upvote the answer. If nobody has upvoted it within two days, you will be eligible to accept your own answer, so do that. (If for some reason it's really urgent, like a security fix or something, you might leverage the typical ways of drawing more attention to a question - but keep in mind that other high-rep users are quite wary of any appearance of being a voting ring.)
4. **Now you have a valid duplicate target, so use that.**
5. If other users try to give you trouble for doing any of this (especially if they think you're abusing your gold Python badge to dupe questions to "your" question, e.g. for some underhanded rep-gaining purpose), feel free to refer them here. Also: in the comments, feel free to cite the fact that you are the maintainer of the library in question. Also feel free to tell people honestly that you don't care about the reputation (assuming that you don't).

### Asking people to update for multiple different reasons

> That means for many questions my answer is: "Please update pypdf"
>
> But the questions are very different. They are not duplicates.

Then the answer is actually different. The trick is to **say more than** "please update pypdf". That wouldn't be a particularly good answer even if you only proposed to write it once.

In particular, please explain:

- What version of PyPDF fixes the issue (and what version is current as of writing the answer)?
- What is the relevant change that occurred in that version, and how does that change address the issue?
- Why exactly was there an issue before the change?

Comment: I appreciate this answer since it suggests the uses the appropriate solution to multiple questions with the same answer, and suggests, a better way to write “it’s a bug” answers.

Comment: this discussion looks related: [Posting an intentionally too broad/unclear catch-all question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265500/839601)